# NodeJS 'Can\'t set headers after they are sent.'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I build an app with Express fetching twits from twitter. Each call is fetching 200 twits (or less if the number is smaller) and total amount is 1800. I use time interval to fetch twits few times and pass id of the last twit as the id of the first twit from next call. Sometimes it works well but sometimes I face this error: 'Can\'t set headers after they are sent.'

I browsed several similar threads and then updated my error instructions to send empty res objects. But it didn't change anything. How can I fix my code to get rid of this bug?

```
T.get('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name: account, count: 200} , function(err, data){
    if(err){return res.send();};

    var i = 0;
    last_id = data[data.length-1].id_str;
    for(var n in data)
    {
        twits.push({content: data[n].text, date: data[n].created_at});
    }
    if(data.length < 200){
        var twitsToSend = filter(twits);
        return res.send(twitsToSend);       
    }

        var getTwits = setInterval(function()
        {
            T.get('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name: account, count: 200, max_id: last_id},function(err,data){
                if(err){return res.send();};

                last_id = data[data.length-1].id_str;
                if(data.length < 200){
                    var twitsToSend = filter(twits);
                    return res.send(twitsToSend);

                }
                for(var n in data)
                {
                    twits.push({content: data[n].text, date: data[n].created_at});
                }

            });
                ++i;
                if(i==9)
                    {   
                        clearInterval(getTwits);
                        var twitsToSend = filter(twits);
                        return res.send(twitsToSend);
                    };
        },845);

    });
});
```

Comment: You're returning `res.send` multiple times in a setInterval that happens every 845 seconds. It looks like you don't want to call `res.send()` until all your data is asynchronously fetched.

Comment: hey that seems to be working. I've just created additional clearInterval function within my conditional . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should add `clearInterval(getTwits);` to the inside of the `getTwits` function:

```
if(data.length < 200){
                clearInterval(getTwits);
                var twitsToSend = filter(twits);
                return res.send(twitsToSend);
            }
```

Right now if the Twitter API returns less than 200 results you do a `res.send` but never stop the interval timer, so it will fetch more results and again try the `res.send`, which may be the source of your error.